# Caffeine taking up 2.88GB virtual memory

Tags: macos, leopard, virtual-memory

[image: Caffeine]

[Caffeine](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/) is a small program. Why is it taking up so much virtual memory or am I reading this wrong?

Edit: persists across application and os restarts

Comment: Can I suggest talking to the developer of Caffeine - it might be a bug that they want to fix, or they might be able to shed some light on the situation.

Comment: i thought may be was misreading it or it was benign, but I guess reporting it would be prudent.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - did you ever hear back from the Caf dev?

Comment: nope, have been too busy of late. I will post an answer if I figure it out/ hear back.

Comment: @bronze your RZISE (real memory size), that is amount of memory used by currently allocated objects is only 7.45MB. That’s perfectly acceptable! Don’t worry about “Virtual”.

Comment: I was just curious about that large number, that all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So apparently I was reading it wrong. According to Thomas Franzén ( lightheadsw )

> Virtual memory size is a meaningless
>   number for most uses. An application
>   having a big virtual memory size
>   doesn't affect you, because it's just
>   a virtual memory space. The column you
>   should be looking at is RSIZE. That's
>   the actual amount of physical RAM an
>   application is using.

I verified with [ObjectAlloc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001882-CJBJFIDD) and it seems like it is using only 8MB or so.

[image: Memory test of Caffeine]

Answer (score 1):

On my machine, it's using 30.2 MB, so you're right that yours is doing something out of the ordinary.

When you reboot, does it start at a lower number, or immediately jump to this level?
Do you usually have it clicked? (I don't)
Is it adding any messages to your console log?
What version of Caffeine are you running?

Comment: thanks for the quick response, here is what i found. It directly jumps to this number. I have it on all the time. this is the only log message I could find  `[0x0-0x11011].com.lightheadsw.Caffeine[419] SystemFlippers: didn't consume all data for long ID 0 (pBase = 0x100129f90, p = 0x100129f94, pEnd = 0x100129f98)` and I am running version 1.1.1